# Angular JS Failed to display the Grand Total of the Row

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wcf

I am trying to calculate grand total of the two column Money In and Money Out . I defined two function to calculate total but problem is its is displaying NAN at bottom of the web page instead of showing total . I am wondering where i did wrong

Here is the Angular JS Code ..

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
        app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
            $scope.IsVisible = false;
            $scope.Search = function () {
                var post = $http({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/TranscationDetails/" + encodeURIComponent($scope.Account_Number),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                    }
                });

                post.then(function (response) { // .success(function(data => .then(function(response
                    var data = response.data; // extract data from resposne
                    $scope.Customers = JSON.parse(data); // eval(data.d) => JSON.parse(data)
                    $scope.IsVisible = true;
                }, function (err) {
                    $window.alert(err);
                });
            }

            $scope.grandTotal = function () {
                return $scope.Customers.reduce(function (previousTotal, m) {
                    return previousTotal + parseFloat(m.Deposit);
                }, 0); // Send in 0 as the default previousTotal
            }

            $scope.grandTotal1 = function () {
                return $scope.Customers.reduce(function (previousTotal, m) {
                    return previousTotal + parseFloat(m.Withdrawal);
                }, 0); // Send in 0 as the default previousTotal
            }
        });
    </script>
    @*<script type="text/javascript">
      var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
      app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
          $scope.IsVisible = false;
          $scope.Search = function () {
              var post = $http({
                  method: "GET",
                  url: "http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/TranscationDetails/" + encodeURIComponent($scope.Account_Number),
                  dataType: 'json',
                  headers: {
                      'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                  }
              });

              post.then(function (response) { // .success(function(data => .then(function(response
                  var data = response.data; // extract data from resposne
                  $scope.Customers = JSON.parse(data); // eval(data.d) => JSON.parse(data)
                  $scope.IsVisible = true;
              }, function (err) {
                  $window.alert(err);
                  });

              $scope.grandTotal = function () {
                  return $scope.Customers.reduce(function (previousTotal, m) {
                      return previousTotal + parseFloat(m.Deposit);
                  }, 0); // Send in 0 as the default previousTotal 
              }
              $scope.grandTotal1 = function () {
                  return $scope.Customers.reduce(function (previousTotal, m) {
                      return previousTotal + parseFloat(m.Withdrawal);
                  }, 0); // Send in 0 as the default previousTotal 
              }
          }
      });
    </script>*@
    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
        Account Number:
        <input type="text" ng-model="Account_Number" />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="Search()" />
        <hr />
        <table style="border: solid 2px Green; padding: 5px;" ng-show="IsVisible">
            @*<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">*@
            <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: skyblue; color: maroon;">
                <th></th>
                <th> Account Number</th>
                 <th> Money In</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                 <th> Money Out</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Account Balance</th>

                <th></th>
                <th></th>

            </tr>
            <tbody ng-repeat="m in Customers">
                <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: skyblue; color: maroon;">
                    <td></td>
                    <td><span>{{m.Account_Number}}</span></td>
                     <td><span>{{m.Deposit| currency:"£"}}</span></td>
                    <td><span>{{m.Date}}</span></td>

                    <td><span>{{m.Withdrawal | currency:"£"}}</span></td>
                    <td><span>{{m.Date}}</span></td>
                    <td><span>{{m.Account_Balance| currency:"£"}}</span></td>

                </tr>


            </tbody>
            <table style="border: solid 2px Green; padding: 5px;" ng-show="IsVisible">
                <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: skyblue; color: maroon;">
                    <td>Total Money In:</td>

                    <td>{{grandTotal()}}</td>

                    <td>Total Money Out:</td>

                    <td>{{grandTotal1()}}</td>

                    <td>Account Balance:</td>

                    <td>{{m.Account_Balance| currency:"£"}}</td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </table>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Result when i run the application.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you nested your total functions within the search function.  The resulting script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
  app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
      $scope.IsVisible = false;
      $scope.Search = function () {
          var post = $http({
              method: "GET",
              url: "http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/TranscationDetails/" + encodeURIComponent($scope.Account_Number),
              dataType: 'json',
              headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
              }
          });

          post.then(function (response) { // .success(function(data => .then(function(response
              var data = response.data; // extract data from resposne
              $scope.Customers = JSON.parse(data); // eval(data.d) => JSON.parse(data)
              $scope.IsVisible = true;
          }, function (err) {
              $window.alert(err);
              });
      }

      $scope.grandTotal = function () {
          return $scope.Customers.reduce(function (previousTotal, m) {
              return previousTotal + parseFloat(m.Deposit);
          }, 0); // Send in 0 as the default previousTotal 
      }

      $scope.grandTotal1 = function () {
          return $scope.Customers.reduce(function (previousTotal, m) {
              return previousTotal + parseFloat(m.Withdrawal);
          }, 0); // Send in 0 as the default previousTotal 
      }
  });
</script>
```

Also, in this case use ng-if rather than ng-show so that the total functions wont run and throw errors to the console when no customer is found.

Here's a snippet with mock data so that you can see it working.

```js
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope, $http, $window) {
  $scope.IsVisible = false;
  $scope.Search = function() {
    $scope.Customers = [{
      Account_Number:17,
      Deposit: 10000,
      Withdrawal: 0,
      Account_Balance: 10000
    }, {
      Account_Number:17,
      Deposit: 0,
      Withdrawal: 2000,
      Account_Balance: 8000
    }, {
      Account_Number:17,
      Deposit: 1500,
      Withdrawal: 0,
      Account_Balance: 6500
    }];
    $scope.IsVisible = true;
  };
  $scope.grandTotal = function() {
    return $scope.Customers.reduce(function(previousTotal, m) {
      return previousTotal + parseFloat(m.Deposit);
    }, 0); // Send in 0 as the default previousTotal 
  };
  $scope.grandTotal1 = function() {
    return $scope.Customers.reduce(function(previousTotal, m) {
      return previousTotal + parseFloat(m.Withdrawal);
    }, 0); // Send in 0 as the default previousTotal 
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyController">

  <div>
    Account Number:
    <input type="text" ng-model="Account_Number" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="Search()" />
    <hr />
    <table style="border: solid 2px Green; padding: 5px;" ng-if="IsVisible">
      <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: skyblue; color: maroon;">
        <th></th>
        <th> Account Number</th>
        <th> Money In</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th> Money Out</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Account Balance</th>

        <th></th>
        <th></th>

      </tr>
      <tbody ng-repeat="m in Customers">
        <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: skyblue; color: maroon;">
          <td></td>
          <td><span>{{m.Account_Number}}</span></td>
          <td><span>{{m.Deposit| currency:"£"}}</span></td>
          <td><span>{{m.Date}}</span></td>

          <td><span>{{m.Withdrawal | currency:"£"}}</span></td>
          <td><span>{{m.Date}}</span></td>
          <td><span>{{m.Account_Balance| currency:"£"}}</span></td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table style="border: solid 2px Green; padding: 5px;" ng-if="IsVisible">
      <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: skyblue; color: maroon;">
        <td>Total Money In:</td>

        <td>{{grandTotal()}}</td>

        <td>Total Money Out:</td>

        <td>{{grandTotal1()}}</td>

        <td>Account Balance:</td>

        <td>{{m.Account_Balance| currency:"£"}}</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I know that but it is irrelevant to your issue.  I simply mocked up some data since your url is not a public site and is inaccessible from here.

Comment: Have you run the code snippet to see that the totaling is working?

Comment: I have modified my answer to show you how your code should look in addition to the working snippet with mock data

Comment: Did you move your totaling functions out of the search function?